# Multiple Customizers

Tags: customization, theme-customizer

So I'm building quite a lot of convenient customization options into the wp_customizer and while it does offer the ability to organize settings into tabs, it still seems to be getting rather crowded.

Ideally I'd love to have multiple customizer menus each dedicated to specific sections so instead of just having Appearance > Customizer for example I'd have Appearance > Customize Structure, Appearance > Customize Fonts, Appearance > Customize Colors..

Each would go to a page very much like the current customizer page but the settings would be dedicated to specific customizations.

Is there any way to generate more than one customizer?

Answer (score -3):

Have you tried utilising "Panels" and then "Sections"?

$wp_customize->add_panel..........